# jquery show() not work unless invoke alert after that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i use `jquery.show()` to display a `div`, but I cannot see the display effect, unless invoke alert after show method like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
 $("#screenAsLayer").show();
 $("#screenAsLayer_content").show();
 alert("aa");
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="screenAsLayer" class="screenAsLayer"></div>
<div id="screenAsLayer_content" class="screenAsLayer_content">
  <img src="..../img/....gif">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.screenAsLayer{
 display:none;
 z-index:9;
 position:abosolute;
}
.screenAsLayer_content{
 display:none;
 z-index:10;
 position:abosolute;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/3U6mE/)

Comment: Don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is ready?

Comment: And you have a typo in your position attribute.

Comment: write a code inside `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: This, I would like to see in a jsFiddle because what you're saying doesn't seem possible unless there's more to your problem than you're showing here (like a long running piece of javascript that follows).

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/3U6mE/

Comment: i think you want to see an effect like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XZ8Yg/

Comment: Please [**read the jQuery tutorial**](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this out:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#screenAsLayer").show();
 $("#screenAsLayer_content").show();
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/3U6mE/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle to show working example @TiagoMarinho